# Android screen missing elements defined in XML

Tags: android, xml, mobile

I am new to Android development. I have created many screens and all are working quite nicely except one.
I am not sure why screen is not coming up as per XML. Below is my code :

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dip"
    android:id="@+id/linearMain">

   <TextView
        android:id="@+id/courseTitle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:textColor="#2258A2"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/assignmentTitle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
         />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lesson"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:text="Lesson : Lecture 5"
         />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/dueDate"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:text="Due Date : Nov 20, 2014"
         />
   <TextView
        android:id="@+id/marks"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:text="Marks : 20"
         />

   <Button android:id="@+id/btnDownload"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Download"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

And here is main class :

```
public class AssignmentDetail extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_announcement_detail);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    //String course = intent.getStringExtra(Assignments.COURSE);
    //TextView textview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.courseTitle);
    //textview.setText(course);

    String announcementTitle = intent.getStringExtra(Announcement.ANNOUCEMENT_TITTLE);
    TextView announcementTitleTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.annoucementTitle);
    announcementTitleTextView.setText(announcementTitle);



}
```

And here is output :

[image]

You can see there are 4 textView and one button in my xml but i can see only onr textView in output, why it is so and how to fix it.

Thanks..
Anjum

Comment: are you sure you are using layout in your setcontent method

Comment: yes,   setContentView(R.layout.activity_announcement_detail);

Comment: it seems that u r using some other layout xml..try removing textview and run it..if it still shows that Assignment #1 then ur xml  itslef is wrong

Comment: @random, how can i mark your answer as correct ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure following stuff is correct in ur activity :

- Make some changes in layout file and see it display that changed stuff
- Correct xml file layout is specified at setContentView.

It seems that you are using some other layout xml..try removing textview and run it..if it still shows that Assignment #1 then ur xml itslef is wrong

Answer (score 1):

I think you are not inflating the right XML layout file.
You can see that the TextView that you modify at the end of your code is not present in the XLM file. Therefore the layout that you inflate cannot be the one you are showing us or you would have an error at run time.